# Why I can't fill arraylist in Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, cycle

This is my method:

```
public void Read() {
    try{
        File fXmlFile = new File("C://Students.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");

        Student s = new Student(); // Creating a new object

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                s.First_Name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
                Student.Last_Name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent();

                Student.ID = eElement.getAttribute("id");
                Student.Spec = eElement.getElementsByTagName("spec").item(0).getTextContent();
                Student.Course = eElement.getElementsByTagName("course").item(0).getTextContent();

                Student.Ratingstr = eElement.getElementsByTagName("rating").item(0).getTextContent();

                students.add(new Student());
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

public static void main(String argv[]){
    Student y = new Student();
    y.Read();        
}
```

and these are my class fields:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
public static String First_Name;
public static String Last_Name;
public static String ID;
public static String Spec;
public static String Course;
public static String Ratingstr;
public float Rating;
```

Why I'm filling the second "s"-object or second student but not the first?
I mean when I wrote first index with my first object of Student in the first cycle then I need to fill second index with second Student but I fill First and the second index only with Second Student. I whrite over the first index in second loop. Why is that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please reframe it to make clear what you require?

Comment: This post looks more like a text message on your cell phone than a question on SO.

Comment: don't edit your questions like this.... http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: also... check my answer and see why your method can't work...

Comment: @Hristo, please don't recycle your questions into other questions in order to drill into further answers -- post new questions instead (if you can't, the first part of this comment still applies).

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, you cant place `students` inside `Student` class. This is not a good idea, you must create, for example a `ClassRoom` class with `students` list:

Something like:

```
class Student {
    public String firstName;
    public String fastName;
    public String id;
    public String spec;
    public String course;
    public String ratingstr;
    public float rating;
}
```

And

```
class ClassRoom  {
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    // PUT HERE THE READ METHOD!!!!


    // optional:
    public String print() {
        // print each student inside room.students 
        for (Student s : room.students) {
            // you must have a Student.print() method!!!
            s.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    ClassRoom room = new ClassRoom();
    room.read();

    room.print();
}
```

---

**Second**: You are not filling your array list either your object in the right way:

```
Student.Last_Name
```

is refering statically to class `Student`, not to `Student s` instance, the right way is:

```
s.Last_Name
```

This line is inserting a new empty instance of Student in students list, **not** the `s` instance you filled.

```
students.add(new Student());
```

So your iteration iside `read` method of `ClassRoom` class will be like:

```
if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    s.firstName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
    s.lastName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent();
    s.id = eElement.getAttribute("id");
    s.spec = eElement.getElementsByTagName("spec").item(0).getTextContent();
    s.course = eElement.getElementsByTagName("course").item(0).getTextContent();
    s.ratingstr = eElement.getElementsByTagName("rating").item(0).getTextContent();

    // add the FILLED instance of Student s to ClassRoom.students!!!
    students.add(s);
}
```

---

**Third (optional)**:

- Is highly recommended you declare your `Student` attributes `private` and create `getter`s and `setter`s to modify them safely.
- Java conventions say you variable names must start with `LOWERCASE` and your `Class` names with `UPPERCASE` so: `class Student`, and `String firstName`.

Comment: "First of all, you cant place students inside Student class". Well obviously, you 'can'.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta of course you can place a list and call it students... its allowed by JVM... but i'm speaking about design issues... the desired result mark the rules of what can be or not be done... and desired result **in this concrete case** sais this is a not accepted design rule to store students.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static fields. If you use static fields they are the same for every single object of the class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new instance of the Student in every loop iteration, you need to populate that instance, and then you need to add that specific instance (not another new one) to the list, i.e.:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
// create a new instance of the Student in every loop iteration
            Student s = new Student();// Creating a new object
// ...and then populate that instance:
            s.First_Name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
...
// add that specific instance (not another new one) to the list
            students.add(s);
```

Comment: Question: with `Node`s is mandatory to create a new instance of the class each time? Also i guess `students` list must be outside `Student` class

Answer (score -1):

Do this.

```
s.First_Name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
s.Last_Name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent();
s.ID = eElement.getAttribute("id");
s.Spec = eElement.getElementsByTagName("spec").item(0).getTextContent();
s.Course = eElement.getElementsByTagName("course").item(0).getTextContent();
s.Ratingstr = eElement.getElementsByTagName("rating").item(0).getTextContent();

students.add(s);
```

Also at the beginning of the loop, make a new instance of `Student`. Right now you've made only one. You should make one for every time you run the loop.

Comment: `students` list is inside `Student` so it's impossible to fill with a new instance each time....

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. How is it "impossible" to add a new instance of a class to an arraylist?

Comment: I don't say that... i mean students list is inside Student class... if you create a new Student instance each iteration you delete the list... please check my answer to see what I mean

Comment: No you don't delete the list. I am asking to create a new instance at the start of the loop, fill it up, and then add it to the list. Is that very difficult to understand?

Comment: where you create `students` list?